# Eloquent receive a value like a column name?

Tags: php, laravel-5, orm, eloquent, mariadb

I have the follow model in `Laravel Eloquent`:

```
<?php

namespace Sac\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class PatientsDevices extends Eloquent
{

    ...

    public static function getDevicesByDateTime() 
    {
        $currrentDateTime = (new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('America/Costa_Rica')))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        return self::where('monitor', '=', 1)
            ->whereBetween($currrentDateTime, ['start_date_time', 'end_date_time'])
            ->get();

    }

    ...
}
```

With this, I try to build the next SQL sentence:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `patients_devices` 
WHERE 
(
    `monitor` = 1 AND 
    '2019-03-23 13:11:48' BETWEEN `start_date_time` AND `end_date_time`
)
```

But instead Eloquent build:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `patients_devices` 
WHERE 
(
    `monitor` = 1 AND 
    `2019-03-23 13:11:48` BETWEEN `start_date_time` AND `end_date_time`
)
```

The little big difference are (') and (`) (backquote/backtick) into where condition, since the first is recognized as string but the second like a literal column name.

In my model, I have a public method that get retrive to data collection with theses conditions: the monitor value is 1 and
a timestamp exists between two datetime columns (start and end).

**My problem:** I'm forced in use models, and I see that I use of `whereBetween` method, recognize `$currrentDateTime` like as column when should recognize as value, since in SQL I can use columns and values positions on the clause where whitout restrincts.

This is a `Eloquent` limitation? or I'm developing of wrong way the logic SQL?. I can resolve it the other way using models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you want to get the entries in between these dates?

```
self::where('monitor', '=', 1)
    ->where('start_date_time', '<=', $currentDateTime)
    ->where('end_date_time', '>=', $currentDateTime)
    ->get();
```

If you want to use `whereBetween()`, the syntax is `->whereBetween('column', [values])`, so I doubt it fits in your case.

Comment: Thanks @senty, is you right about of the documentation, the first param is a column name, so I supposed I could pass a value like a column name. You code work.